# HTML data submit button returns php source file and does not send data to mysql table

Tags: php, apache

Installed Apache2 and uncommented php7 module with: https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Location of apache config in my machine:

```
/etc/apache2
```

Installed MySQl with homebrew according to : https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-macos/#

Locations of MySQl on my machine is:

mysql is /usr/local/bin/mysql
mysql is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Wrote unique mysql tables under same database for two unique html registration forms written on Visual Studio Code. Live server extension on VS Code allows browser to display and navigate html/css but after I submit data on signup.html, my interpreters.php code is automatically returned as a  download with unknown server script injection.

**signup.html** file displays on browser

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signup.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navigationbar.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sign up with ...</title>
        </head>
        <header> 
                   <div id="menu-content">
                           <div class="navbar">
                                   <ol>
                                   <li> <a href="home.html"> Home</a> </li>
                                   <li> <a href="signup.html">For Professionals</a> </li>
                                   <li> <a href="search.html">Request Service </a> </li>
                                   </ol>
                           </div>
               
                   </div>
                    
                      
        </header>
<body>

<form name="signup" action="interpreters.php" method="get" style="border:1px solid #ffff">

  <div class="container">
    <h1><center>Professional Interpreter Registration</center></h1>

    <label for="first">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name..." name="first" required>

    <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your last name..." name="last" required>

    <label for="industry"><b> Industry: </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your industry..." name="industry" required>

    <label for="type"><b> Service Type: </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description:Translation of legal documents Mandarin and Arabic/Interpret Italian through video only." name="industry" required>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" required>


 

    <div class="clearfix">
    
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn name="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The action that the html is linked to is the following interpreters.php

```
<?php
// php code to Insert data into mysql database from input text
if(isset($_GET ['insert'] ) )

{
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "......";
$databaseName = "registrations";

// get values form input text and number

$last = $_GET ['last'];
$first = $_GET['lfirst'];
$industry = $_GET['industry'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

// connect to mysql database using mysqli

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

// mysql query to insert data

$query = "INSERT INTO `interpreters`(`last`, `first`, `industry`, 'type', 'email') VALUES ('$last','$first','$industry', '$type', '$email' )";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

// check if mysql query successful

if($result)

{
    echo 'Data Inserted';
}

else
{
    echo 'Data Not Inserted';
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>

<html>
<body>
Thank you, <?php echo $_POST['first']; ?><br />
We will contact you at <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?><br />
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apache is not configured to process PHP files, rather it is sending out the unprocessed source.

Comment: I will configure Apache to process properly and update my post with the result. Thank you!